# How to generate several random blocks of repeating numbers in one vector?

Tags: r, random

This should be easy in R, but I can't think of a solution. Let's say that I want to generate a sequence that randomly varies between three numbers: -1, 0, and 1. That's easily done with:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <-rep(c(-1,0,1),20)
dat
[1] -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0  1 -1  0
```

But how can I use `rep()` or something comparable to generate a sequence with these three numbers so that, say, the "1" repeats in a relatively longer, continuous sequence -- 5 times in a row, for example, in this example.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is create a vector with that varies between -1, 0, and 1 with a conspicuous bias for any given number to repeat continuously for, say, 25% to 50% of the vector's length, along with another bias for 0s and 1s.

An portion of the example output I'm looking for via the illustration above might be:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Any suggestions? Thanks much!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking, but you can use `sample` to randomly sample from a set of numbers of your choosing. For example, `sample(c(-1, 0, 1), 20, replace = T)`

Comment: for that just do `rep(c(0, 1, -1, 0), c(5, 7, 7, 5))`

Comment: ssp3nc3r, yes, that's true. But how might I use sample() to control how many continuously repeats of each number are generated? Let's say I created a 1000 random numbers in this case but wanted any one number to repeat at least 50 times.

Comment: TRy `rep(sample(c(0, 1, -1, 0)), c(5, 8, 7, 6))`

Comment: akrun, thanks. your example is one solution.